# Which SDK version of firebase-ads that is working?

Tags: python, kivy, admob, buildozer

I am implementing ads to my kivy application now, but my ads weren't showing up. I think the issue of it is because of the firebase-ads version of android gradle dependencies.

When I tried the older version, I managed to convert my python-kivy code into apk but my ads weren't showing up. (Android API = 30)

```
android.gradle_dependencies = 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.2.0'
```

Therefore, I changed the version to the latest one, but when I tried to convert my python-kivy code into apk, an error occurred because the firebase-ads version of android gradle dependencies is not working.
(Android API = 31)

```
android.gradle_dependencies = 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:21.3.0'
```

Any idea of which firebase-ads version of android gradle dependencies is working now?
My targeting android API is 31.